# WordPress AJAX (php/MySQL) - how to move reusable parts of the code / definitions to external file or function?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, scope

I'm writing a WP ajax call to interface with an external MySQL database. So I have the ajax.php file where I have all of my ajax calls defined, each one represented by a separate function and a corresponding action, like this:

**ajax.php**

```
// MySQL ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_mysql_ajax', 'mysql_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mysql_ajax', 'mysql_ajax' );

function mysql_ajax() {
//some code
} // End MySQL ajax
```

In my MySQL ajax call I use procedural **mysqli** to communicate with the database. I have pieces of code that are used multiple times, like this one:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $var['sql'])) {
    echo "SQL: OK. Query:\n" . $var['sql'] . "\n\n";
} else {
    echo "SQL: ERROR.\n" . mysqli_error($conn) . "\n\nQuery:\n" . $var['sql'] . "\n\n";
}
```

I want to move this code into a function and out of the ajax call function, like this:

**MySQL.php**

```
function mysql_insert_into_table($table){

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $table['sql'])) {
        echo "SQL: OK. Query:\n" . $table['sql'] . "\n\n";
    } else {
        echo "SQL: ERROR.\n" . mysqli_error($conn) . "Query:\n" . $table['sql'] . "\n\n";
    }
}
```

But when I do this MySQL queries stop working and I can't see any SQL errors in the console. What am I doing wrong?

What I have managed to do so far is to move vars holding the SQL queries for creating my tables into a separate .php file and make them accessible inside the ajax call with the help of "global":

```
global $myTable;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's not much anyone can do but speculate. I'd recommend browsing the [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) documentation and re-asking your question with code you have tried so we have a [Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The `require` sounds like it's failing, likely due to a PHP error in that file or an incorrect path being passed to the `require` statement.\

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear but to make a ajax request try:

```
      $.ajax({
url:'file.php',
method:'POST',
data:{
id:id,
value:option
},
success:function(data){
    }
    );
```

Thanks!!